# Trying to access an associative array item via timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So I have a MySQL object, which has columns (keys) for timestamp, category, and value.

Timestamp is a UNIX timestamp. Category is an emotion word. Value is a numeric value.

Here's my code:

```
foreach ($twitromney['timestamp']) {

echo $twitromney['timestamp']['value'];

}
```

Now, this should display the value per timestamp, right? This is how ONE of the arrays looks (the object has hundreds of these):

```
Array ( [category] => composed [value] => 330 [timestamp] => 1344384476.94 )
```

What I am trying to do is get the value per category per timestamp. Except for value, which is variable, both timestamp and category should repeat. I.e., there should be multiple 1344384476.94s, as well as several composed category values.

Once I get that (I don't think I need help with this), I am going to add the values for a particular category for a particular day (by converting the timestamp) together and output this.

Comment: what exactly is in that $twitromney array?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach ($twitromney as $flip) {

    echo "$flip['category'], $flip['timestamp'], $flip['value'] <br />";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't understand your question but you have supplied wrong arguments in your `foreach`, you can try this

```
foreach ($twitromney as $item) {
    echo $item['timestamp'].'<br />';
}
```

to echo every `timestamp` instead of

```
foreach ($twitromney['timestamp']){ 
    echo $twitromney['timestamp']['value'];
}
```

If you see [**this example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XGyqrY) then you'll get an idea.